# P5.JS - Calulcate a 3 point intersection

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to calculate a `3 point intersection` for a pong game made using javascript and its library p5.js.

I need to calculate if the ball hit the paddle.
General idea:
`var MaxTopPos = player.y;`
`var MaxBottomPos = player.y + player.height;` Which player.height = 100.
Where player = the paddle. The other paddle will be the computer.

At first I thought maybe I can use `dist(this.x, this.y, player.x, ...)`
and then I got caught on the `player.y`.
`this.x` and `this.y` is the ball position and `player.x` is the paddle's position from the left side of the screen.

My question is how can I take the `MaxTopPos` and the `MaxBottomPos` and check if the ball hit somewhere in between or right on the edge? So i can then calculate a ton more stuff I found from [this thread](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/in-pong-how-do-you-calculate-the-balls-direction-when-it-bounces-off-the-paddl). What I am trying to do is check if the ball hit the paddle and if it did send it in the opposite direction.

Here's a visual:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just treat the ball as a rectangle and then use rectangle-rectangle collision detection between the ball's bounding rect and the paddle.

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on collision detection in Processing [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection), but the basics are the same in P5.js and JavaScript.

Basically, you'd do this:

```
//evaluates to true if rectOne and rectTwo are colliding
if(rectOneRight > rectTwoLeft && rectOneLeft < rectTwoRight && rectOneBottom > rectTwoTop && rectOneTop < rectTwoBottom){
```

Comment: Sorry but that didnt work. I did if((player.x + player.width) > ball.x && player.x < (ball.x + ball.width)) { this.speed = -20 (reversed) }

Comment: Which if the ball was in the center of the padding. like between the left and right points the velocity of the ball should of reversed.

Comment: also I made sure the ball was the same width as the paddle.

Comment: What if I checked the top and bottom points of the paddle, then looped through the two points and put each of the points that are between the top and the bottom in a array using a loop statement. then checked if the ball hit any of the x positions that are in the array. To me that sounds like alot of processing for the computer constantly.

Comment: Lol, my fault I did this.width for the ball instead of the variable i had given it which is this.diameter. it works now.